# Get URLs inside a HTML page with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this code:

```
    foreach (HtmlNode node in hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='compTitle options-toggle']//a"))
    {
        string s=("node:" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
    }
```

I want to get urls in tags like this:

```
<div class="compTitle options-toggle">

    <a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="http://www.bestbuy.com">
               <b>Huawei</b> Products - Best Buy
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to get "http://www.bestbuy.com" and "**Huawei** Products - Best Buy"

what should I do? Is my code correct?

Comment: `Is my code correct?` - why you can't check whether your code is correct?

Comment: it does not return me the URL

Comment: then you should know the answer to the question *"Is my code correct?"*

Comment: did you read `what should I do`? I meant if it is not correct anybody help me.OK?

Comment: the href is missing the closing double quote

Comment: @AlkisGiamalis tnx I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example of working code

```
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml("<div class=\"compTitle options-toggle\"><a class=\" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24\" href=\"http://www.bestbuy.com\"><b>Huawei</b> Products - Best Buy</a></div>");

        var tags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='compTitle options-toggle']//a").ToList();

        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            var link = tag.Attributes["href"].Value; // http://www.bestbuy.com
            var text = tag.InnerText; // Huawei Products - Best Buy
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The closing double quote should fix the selecting (it worked for me).

Get the plain text as

```
 string contentText = node.InnerText;
```

or having the Huawei word in bold, like this:

```
 string contentHtml = node.InnerHtml;
```